# How to get children of elements by Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

I understand that `puppeteer` get its own handles rather than standard `DOM` elements, but I don't understand why I cannot continue the same query by found elements as

```
const els = await page.$$('div.parent');

for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    const img = await els[i].$('img').getAttribute('src');
    console.log(img);
    const link = await els[i].$('a').getAttribute('href');
    console.log(link);
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? what error does it return?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Problem

The element handles are necessary as an abstraction layer between the Node.js and browser runtime. The actual DOM elements are not sent to the Node.js environment.

That means when you want to get an attribute from an element, there has to be data transferred to the browser (which DOM element to use) and back (the result).

### Solution

Therefore, the result from `await els[i].$('img')` is not really the DOM element, but only a wrapper that links to the element in the browser environment. To get the attribute, you have to use a function like [`elementHandle.$eval`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleevalselector-pagefunction-args-1):

```js
const imgSrc = await els[i].$eval('img', el => el.getAttribute('src'));
```

This runs the `querySelector` function on the given element and executes the given function to return its attribute.

Comment: In this case, can be usefull cause they have one Image children, but if I've multiple images inside, how to get all srcs?

        const data = await aliexpress.page.evaluate(() => {
            const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div > img'))
            return tds.map(img => img.src)
        });

But I dont wanna use .page.evaluate.

Answer (score 10):

You can use function `$eval`

```js
const els = await page.$$('div.parent');

for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    const img = await els[i].$eval('img', i => i.getAttribute('src'));
    console.log(img);
    const link = await els[i].$eval('a', a => a.getAttribute('href'));
    console.log(link);
}
```