# Puppeteer: How to navigate into elements obtained from $$?

Tags: puppeteer

> The following question is similar but the answer are useless: [How to get children of elements by Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55659097/how-to-get-children-of-elements-by-puppeteer). In these answers, users show how to get an attribute of an element. I need to access list of child nodes.

In the page I'm scraping there are 30 boxes with really complex and different content.

My goal was to
- obtain the external boxes (`DIV`s)
- check if some spceific nested html elements are present
- retrieve content of nested element

For example
- first box has image with nested link
- second box has 4 `<P>`s

I am able, thanks to an [answer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61699560/1055279) to retrieve all `DIV`s

I am doing this

```
  const boxes = await page.$$("DIV.a-row DIV.spinnerDeal DIV.box DIV.details")

  boxes.forEach((item) => {
       ... now, for example how to check if the item contains a P with a specific class=
  })
```

So my question is (for example) how to check if the item contains a P with a specific class.

More general question is *how to browser nested elements of each item ?*

I tried

```
boxes.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item.getChildNodes())
  console.log("---")
})
```

But `getChildNodes() is not a function`

Comment: So, based on your previous question you should use the evaluate function inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works for you.

```
const pTags = await page.$x( '//DIV.a-row//DIV.spinnerDeal//DIV.box//DIV.details//p' );
```

After get all ptags and you can check every ptags with parent node, so you can get where it included.